# How to Create Variable Padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, padding, smartphone

When I view my website on a smartphone, some of my menu items are flowing off the page. As a result, I want to give these menu items variable `padding` widths. For example, my `padding-left` and `padding-right` are currently set to `25px`. This works fine on larger screen such as tablets and computers, but it is too high a number when viewing on a smartphone.

I want to make it so that I can set the `padding` to `25px` when viewed on a screen over, say 768px wide, but at only `15px` when viewed on a screen less than 768px wide. Even better would be if the padding would slowly decrease from 25px to 15px as the browser size gets smaller.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

[CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries):

```
/* normal screen CSS */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  /* small screen override CSS */
}
```

Comment: `media queries` is what you are looking for.